# Не понимаю, почему функция выводит None

Tags: python, функции

Функция должна выводить список всех делителей передаваемого ей числа (кроме себя и единицы)

```
def vse_deliteli(integer):
    vsedeliteli = list()
    for i in range(1, integer):
        if integer % i == 0:
            vsedeliteli.append(i)
    return vsedeliteli.remove(1)
print(vse_deliteli(25))
```

Результат *None*, причем проблема именно в *list.remove*, т. к. когда его убираю, все работает нормально.

```
def vse_deliteli(integer):
    vsedeliteli = list()
    for i in range(1, integer):
        if integer % i == 0:
            vsedeliteli.append(i)
    return vsedeliteli
print(vse_deliteli(25))
```

> [1, 5]

Не могу понять, почему получается *None*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращайте не процедуру, а список.
вот так будет работать как вы хотите:

```
def vse_deliteli(integer):
    vsedeliteli = []
    for i in range(1, integer):
        if integer % i == 0:
            vsedeliteli.append(i)

    vsedeliteli.remove(1)

    return vsedeliteli
```

Comment: Точнее сказать - метод remove ничего не возвращает, поэтому и None

Comment: Ну с терминологией у меня - беда =) Спасибо, что уточнили для точности))

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял)

Comment: не забудьте отметить правильный ответ:)